# Al ejecutar composer update, aparecen sucesivos "Conclusion: don't install <paquete> (conflict analysis result)"

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

Estoy tratando de actualizar mi proyecto v5.8 a v6, pero me manda una serie de errores cuando hago el comando `composer update`

Este es mi *composer.json*

```json
    {
        "name": "laravel/laravel",
        "type": "project",
        "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
        "keywords": [
            "framework",
            "laravel"
        ],
        "license": "MIT",
        "require": {
            "php": "^7.2",
            "darryldecode/cart": "^4.2",
            "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
            "laravel/framework": "^6.0",
            "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
            "laraveles/spanish": "^1.5",
            "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0",
            "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "^1.14"
        },
        "require-dev": {
            "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
            "facade/ignition": "^1.4",
            "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
            "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
            "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
            "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.0"
        },
        "config": {
            "optimize-autoloader": true,
            "preferred-install": "dist",
            "sort-packages": true,
            "allow-plugins": {
                "kylekatarnls/update-helper": true
            }
        },
        "extra": {
            "laravel": {
                "dont-discover": []
            }
        },
        "autoload": {
            "psr-4": {
                "App\\": "app/"
            },
            "classmap": [
                "database/seeds",
                "database/factories"
            ]
        },
        "autoload-dev": {
            "psr-4": {
                "Tests\\": "tests/"
            }
        },
        "minimum-stability": "dev",
        "prefer-stable": true,
        "scripts": {
            "post-autoload-dump": [
                "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
                "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
            ],
            "post-root-package-install": [
                "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
            ],
            "post-create-project-cmd": [
                "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
            ]
        }
    }
```

Y este es el resultado que obtengo en consola:

```bash
composer update
```

> Loading composer repositories with package information
> Updating dependencies
> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.0.0 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.0.1 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.0.2 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.1.0 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.2.0 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.3.0 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.4.0 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.4.1 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.5.0 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.5.1 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.6.1 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.6.2 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.7.0 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.8.0 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.10.0 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.10.1 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.11.0 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.12.0 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.13.0 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.13.1 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.14.0 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.15.0 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.15.1 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.17.0 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.17.1 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.0 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.1 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.2 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.4 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.5 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.6 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.7 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.8 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.9 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.10 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.11 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.12 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.13 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.14 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.15 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.16 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.17 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.18 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.19 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.20 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.21 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.22 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.23 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.24 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.25 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.26 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.27 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.28 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.29 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.30 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.31 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.32 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.33 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.34 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.35 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.36 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.37 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.38 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.39 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.40 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.41 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.42 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.43 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.19.0 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.19.1 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.0 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.1 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.2 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.3 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.4 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.5 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.6 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.7 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.8 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.9 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.10 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.11 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.12 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.13 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.14 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.15 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.16 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.17 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.18 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.19 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.20 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.21 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.22 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.23 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.24 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.25 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.26 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.27 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.28 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.29 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.30 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.31 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.32 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.33 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.34 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.35 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.36 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.37 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.38 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.39 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.40 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.41 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.42 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.43 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.44 (conflict analysis result)
> - maatwebsite/excel[2.1.30, ..., 2.1.x-dev] require illuminate/support ^5.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev].
> - maatwebsite/excel[2.1.25, ..., 2.1.29] require illuminate/support 5.0.*|5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.*|5.5.*|5.6.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., 5.6.x-dev].
> - maatwebsite/excel[2.1.21, ..., 2.1.24] require illuminate/support 5.0.*|5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.*|5.5.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., 5.5.x-dev].
> - maatwebsite/excel[2.1.10, ..., 2.1.20] require illuminate/support 5.0.*|5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., 5.4.x-dev].
> - maatwebsite/excel[2.1.4, ..., 2.1.9] require illuminate/support 5.0.*|5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.0.0,
> ..., 5.3.x-dev].
> - maatwebsite/excel[v2.1.0, ..., v2.1.3] require illuminate/support 5.0.*|5.1.*|5.2.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., 5.2.x-dev].
> - Only one of these can be installed: illuminate/support[dev-master, v5.0.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev, v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev, v9.0.0-beta.1, ..., 9.x-dev], laravel/framework[v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev]. laravel/framework replaces illuminate/support and thus cannot coexist with it.
> - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^6.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev].
> - Root composer.json requires maatwebsite/excel ~2.1.0 -> satisfiable by maatwebsite/excel[v2.1.0, ..., 2.1.x-dev].
> Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

---

Esto muestra ahora si uso --with-all-dependencies (-W)

Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires phpunit/phpunit ^8.0, found phpunit/phpunit[8.0.0, ..., 8.5.x-dev] but the package is fixed to 7.5.20 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.

Problem 2
- maatwebsite/excel is locked to version 2.1.30 and an update of this package was not requested.

```
- maatwebsite/excel 2.1.30 requires illuminate/cache ^5.0 -> found illuminate/cache[v5.0.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev] but these
```

were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.

Problem 3
- laravel/framework[v6.19.0, ..., 6.x-dev] require nesbot/carbon ^2.31 -> found nesbot/carbon[dev-master, 2.31.0, ..., 2.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.

```
- laravel/framework[v6.0.0, ..., v6.18.43] require nesbot/carbon ^2.0 -> found nesbot/carbon[dev-master, 2.0.0-beta.1, ..., 2.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.

- Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^6.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev].
```

Comment: Si lees el error, te dice que pruebes con la opción --with-all-dependencies. Has probado esto? Que error te da?

Comment: Hay una [Guía de upgrade](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade). Si te fijas, tiene todo lo necesario para hacer el upgrade de laravel, los requerimientos y los pasos a seguir. Y además dice: *Next, examine any 3rd party packages consumed by your application and verify you are using the proper version for Laravel 6 support.* que por lo que muestra el mensaje de error estás teniendo problemas con maatwebsite/excel[v2.1]